# MySQL calculations with values

Tags: mysql

I'm calculating the `MIN`, `MAX` and the `AVG` of player level:

```
SELECT
     MIN(`p`.`level`) AS 'min',
     MAX(`p`.`level`) AS 'max',
     AVG(`p`.`level`) AS 'avg'
FROM `dfh`.`players` `p`
```

How can how can I get the `p.name` field value which refers to the `MIN` and `MAX`?

Fe. I got this values in my `p` table:

```
Lp. | Name | Level
1   | Test | 12
2   | Tesx | 15
3   | Anot | 150
```

And the query will withdraw the following:

```
MIN: 12
MAX: 150
```

But I want it to withdraw also the `Name` corresponding to the `MIN` and `MAX` value:

```
MIN: 12 Test
MAX: 150 Anot
```

How can I do that?

Comment: MySQL has unfortunately no analytic functions, so you'll have to write a long and boring query.

Comment: @Benoit A big chain of `UNION`s is boring?

Comment: @Michael: :) I should explain what boring is. For me, any code that would need a high dose of Copy-paste is somewhat boring. In those unions, only the aggregate function changes!

Comment: @Benoit, yes, that's boring. Excitement lies in 3 or 4 levels of nested subquery joins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT 'MIN' property, GROUP_CONCAT(p1.name) name, p1.level FROM players p1
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(level) level FROM players) p2
    ON p1.level = p2.level
UNION
SELECT 'MAX' property, GROUP_CONCAT(p1.name) name, p1.level FROM players p1
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(level) level FROM players) p2
    ON p1.level = p2.level
```

---

Query with the highest 'experience' value and any 'id' -

```
SELECT * FROM

  (SELECT 'MIN' property, p1.id, p1.level, p1.name FROM players p1
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        level, MAX(experience) experience
      FROM
        players,
        (SELECT @level:=MIN(level) FROM players) t
      WHERE level = @level
    ) p2
    ON p1.experience = p2.experience AND p1.level = p2.level
  ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) t_min

UNION

SELECT * FROM 

  (SELECT 'MAX' property, p1.id, p1.level, p1.name FROM players p1
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        level, MAX(experience) experience
      FROM
        players,
        (SELECT @level:=MAX(level) FROM players) t
      WHERE level = @level
    ) p2
    ON p1.experience = p2.experience AND p1.level = p2.level
  ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) t_max
```

Use this dataset as a subquery to join with another table -

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM

    (SELECT 'MIN' property, p1.id, p1.level, p1.name FROM players p1
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          level, MAX(experience) experience
        FROM
          players,
          (SELECT @level:=MIN(level) FROM players) t
        WHERE level = @level
      ) p2
      ON p1.experience = p2.experience AND p1.level = p2.level
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) t_min

  UNION

  SELECT * FROM 

    (SELECT 'MAX' property, p1.id, p1.level, p1.name FROM players p1
      JOIN (
        SELECT
          level, MAX(experience) experience
        FROM
          players,
          (SELECT @level:=MAX(level) FROM players) t
        WHERE level = @level
      ) p2
      ON p1.experience = p2.experience AND p1.level = p2.level
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) t_max
) p
LEFT JOIN guild_member gm
  ON gm.id = p.id
```

Comment: It works fine, but what if there are two players with the same level? It should select one of them in that case, atm. it does select all players with the same level.

Comment: Which of them should be selected?

Comment: Well, there is a `experience` field also so maybe if there are two players (or more) with the same level, we should select this one which `experience` field is highest (something like `ORDER BY p.experience DESC`).

Comment: The second query is fine, but when there are few players with level 1 and experience 0, it does select all that player, it should select one of them - no matter which one. Also, why does it select ALL fields from `players` table? It should just select `level` and `name` in that case. Thank you for your help and I hope you help me fix the last problems.

Comment: To select some fields, change '*' with fields you need (p.\* -> p.level, p.name)

Comment: To select one of records, there should be a unique field, e.g. 'id' field which is unique for each record. Do you have this field?

Comment: Yea, I got unique `id` field. I got another problem with modifing your query: I want it go get the player id from another table like this:
`LEFT JOIN guilds g ON (players.id = g.pid)`, where can I place it so it will only select a players from the `g.pid` instead of whole players table?

Comment: I've added my `LEFT JOIN` there, but its doesn't select any rows now, no errors. Here is the query: `http://paste.ubuntu.com/866864/`

Comment: Take a look at last query in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the low/high names *efficiently*:

```
select 'MIN', level, name from players order by level limit 1
union all
select 'MAX', level, name from players order by level desc limit 1
```

Notice the lack of subqueries...